# NativeScript display images in dynamic grid

Tags: image, listview, gallery, nativescript, stackview

I'm trying to find a way to display 6 images in two columns and 3 rows. 
With for columns and images should be 50%. Here is my code and it does not "overflow" second and third row.

```
<Repeater items="{{ sviKatalozi }}">
        <Repeater.itemsLayout>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="500" height="1000" />
        </Repeater.itemsLayout>
        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
            <Image width="180" margin="10" src="{{ 'http://imageurl' + katalog_image }}" />
        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

I have found perfect solution `<FlexboxLayout>` to arrange things in way I want, but could not find a way to use observables and data binding. It does not work if put `items="{{ sviKatalozi }}"` inside.

```
<FlexboxLayout flexWrap="wrap" height="50%" width="100%" backgroundColor="lightgray">
<Label text="Label 1" width="50%" height="50" backgroundColor="red"/>
<Label text="Label 2" width="50%" height="50" backgroundColor="green"/>
<Label text="Label 3" width="50%" height="50" backgroundColor="blue"/>
<Label text="Label 4" width="100" height="50" backgroundColor="yellow"/>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

Is there any way to make this work? Thanks

Comment: can you please add playground demo link?

Comment: better to show your component code too i.e for 'sviKatalozi'

Comment: Hi guys, here is example https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=WDZiP1   It is not Repeater as I have ListView now but same thing. I want to order it like this https://o.dam-img.rfdcontent.com/cms/003/170/559/1000x400_crop-north-force.jpg

Answer (score 0):

use ngFor like this

```
<GridLayout *ngFor="let item of placesArray" width="50%" class="placeBox">
```

instead of Repeater

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am not using Angular NativieScript so *ngFor would not work.